# Theorem about mean value of iterations of isometries

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, projection

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and let $T\in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ be an isometry, and for every integer n let
$$A_n=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}T^j.$$
Then $A_nv$ converges to $P_Sv$ as n diverges, for every $v\in \mathcal{H}$, where $P_S$ is the orthogonal projection on the space $S:=$Ker$(\mathbb{I} - T)$, i.e. of vectors which are $T$-invariant.

---

I am not able to make any real progress on proving this statement, any hints?

---

**My only observations**:

I saw that if $v\in S$ then, by definition, $Tv=\mathbb{I}v=v$, so that
$$A_nv=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}T^jv = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}v=\frac{n}{n}v=v$$
for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, so that $A_nv \to v=P_Sv$.

The struggle starts when I consider $v\not \in S$.

Comment: Now try seeing what happens for $v \in S^\perp$.

Comment: So since it is the preimmage $(\mathbb{I}-t)^{-1}(0)$, $S$ is a closed subspace, so there exists a $s_0\in S$ that minimizes the distance of $v$ from $S$. In particular $s_0=P_Sv$, but what about $A_n$?

Comment: You are reasoning for an arbitrary vector $v$.  I am suggesting that you consider the special case $v \in S^\perp$.

Comment: Yeah I think i get what you are saying: since $S$ is a closed subspace, there is a $s_0 \in S$ that minimizes the distance to $v$ and $(v-s_0)\in S^{\perp}$.So it is succifient to check where $v\in S^\perp$ is taken by $\lim_{n\to +\infty}A_n(v)$, but my problem is I have no clue on how to start computing such a value.

Comment: My reasoning was:  since $T$ has no non-$0$ fixed points on $S^\perp$, but the limit of $A_n v$ is a $T$-fixed point in $S^\perp$, the limit must actually be $0$.  But maybe it's not so obvious that $A_n v$ converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the subspace $\mathrm{Im}(I - T)$. We can check that $\mathrm{Im}(I - T)^\perp = \mathrm{Ker}(I - T) = \mathrm{Im}(P_S) = S$. Therefore $\mathcal{H} = \overline{\mathrm{Im}(I - T)} \oplus S$ (where overline is the closure). You checked that it holds for $v \in S$.

Let $v \in \mathrm{Im}(I - T)$. Then $v = w - Tv$ for some $w \in \mathcal{H}$. We can check that $P_S v = 0$. Then
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum^{n-1}_{j=0} T^j v = \frac{1}{n} \sum^{n-1}_{j=0} (T^j w - T^{j+1} w) = \frac{1}{n} (w - T^nw) .
$$
(We have a telescoping series.) Since $T$ is an isometry, we can apply the triangle inequality to show that
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum^{n-1}_{j=0} T^j v \to 0 , \quad n \to \infty .
$$
Since $P_S v = 0$, the claim is also true for $v \in \mathrm{Im}(I - T)$.

To finish the argument, we have to check that this holds in the closure as well. To do this, for $v \in \overline{\mathrm{Im}(I - T)}$, we can take a sequence $v_n \in \mathrm{Im}(I - T)$ such that $v_n \to v$ as $n \to \infty$, and use what we have just shown (again, using the fact that $T$ is an isometry).

Comment: Thank you, that's a lot of help. just for clarification: when you said $v=w-Tv$ for some $w \in \mathcal{H}$, you meant that $v=w-Tw$, right?

Comment: Yup, that is a typo indeed!